# How to setup a computer for WIFI testing that is also on a LAN - to allow remote access from LAN but all HTTP out thru Wifi?

Tags: networking, wifi

We have a wifi network that gets a lot of complaints I think are more associated with the hand-held point-of-sales units being used than the wifi. These units scan tickets and then upload barcode data to an upstream server. When a trouble ticket is placed, someone has to physically go to the affected area and troubleshoot. In 99.9% of the time the wifi is ok. In most cases, a restart or swap of the device is all that's needed.

I'd like to re-purpose some laptops about to be replaced as hidden QoS / test systems in any area where repeated issues are reported. The challenge is that I don't know how to have both a LAN connection and wifi connection live at the same time but force all HTTP traffic out only the wifi connection. The LAN connection would allow remote access to view the desktop via RDP or VNC, and the wifi connection would be set to run diagnostics, or browser tests as required.

The default functionality of any system setup for this purpose so far ends up routing/moving all traffic on the faster LAN connection and the wifi is never used.

Once I get the system in place, I see some sort of automated hourly QoS test and update script put in place that emails me the results.

Any ideas how I can something like this setup?

Thanks in advance,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Set a default gateway on the wireless connection but not on the LAN connection.

Comment: Let me think about that. The absence of a LAN default gateway would mean I'd only be able to access the system on the LAN if my remote PC was on the same subnet. The Gateway on the Wifi would mean that it would be sent up/out to the wifi system. I like it - simple and effective. Should have thought of it myself - thanks!!!